# How to inherit Image width and height to video tag

Tags: html, css

Image has width 400x400 as per real image property.
Now I have sibling video which should have the same width and height of the image.
How can I inherit Image width and height property to video tag

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" >
<video controls="">
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder {
  position: relative;
}

#stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/mJoyPO

Comment: If your image is always 400x400, just add `height="400" width="400"` to the video tag.

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript?

Comment: First, an `<img>` tag MUST self-close, like `<img ... />` second, if you know the dimensions, can you not just statically set them in css?

Comment: siblings can't inherit from each other. inheritance only works in a parent/child situation. but you could set the div container's size and have both inherit from there.

Comment: @oxguy3 I dnt want to add manually , Since I will different width and height for different images , I just want it dynamically inherit property of height and width

Comment: @Xufox , I know there is a way to do with javascript but want to know if there is way to do it using CSS ,

Comment: @MarcB I dnt want to force width and height to div , According to image height and width will change dynamically ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn stuff into a class and then put div class="stuff" around the video

```
#holder {
  position: absolute;
 height:400px;
 width:auto;
}

.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  height:inherit;
  width:inherit;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.stuff video{position:absolute;
            height:inherit;
            width:inherit;
            vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Can you check the code pen ,  solution does not work .http://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/MwxYpZ

Comment: you have to set a height for the holder but you can set width to auto

Comment: or you could set both to auto

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Accepted the answer